# Return errors as json django rest api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Beginner alert. I am using ListCreateAPIView for listing and creating purposes. Whenever I create through an api it returns responses in json format.

```
{"id":16,"title":"yyyyyyyy","destination_place":[1]}
```

But if there are errors like duplicate slug or title it returns errors like this

```
IntegrityError at /api/holidays/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "holidays_holiday_slug_key"
DETAIL:  Key (slug)=(yyyyyyyy) already exists.
```

Is there any way to return these errors in json format. 
My views

```
class HolidayList(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Holiday.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HolidaySerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser, IsAuthenticated]
```

Model

```
class Holiday(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Title"), max_length=255)
   slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
   destination_place = models.ManyToManyField(to='places.Place',related_name='destination_place',null=True,blank=True)
```

Comment: Please post `Holiday` model.

Comment: Holiday Model added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `HolidaySerializer`, add `UniqueValidator` on `slug` field.

**Example**:

```
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator

class HolidaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    slug = serializers.SlugField(
             max_length=255,
             validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=Holiday.objects.all())])

    class Meta:
        model = Holiday
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'slug', 'destination_place', )
```

This will return back the unique constraint error in the JSON format.

You can customize the message. Look at the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquevalidator).

Comment: Thanks it works. Is there any way to return json errors for all serializers.

Comment: If the serializer is not valid, it will return back the error it encountered. If something that you wished the serializer to encounter, then you can override `validate` method in the serializer.